# PreviewTextInput is fired when the checkbox has focus/Handling the PreviewTextInput in Main window and not allowing child control to steal characters

Tags: .net, wpf, textinput, keydown

I have the following code. The window has a textbox and a checkbox. If I have focus on the anything other than checkbox and type something like 123-456 then for each character `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewTextInput` are firing.

But if I have the focus to checkbox and then type 123-456 then the `PreviewKeyDown` is fired for all the characters whereas `PreviewTextInput` fires only for 123456 and doesn't fire for <kbd>-</kbd>. The hyphen is being handled by the checkbox and not getting passed to `PreviewTextInput`. Is there a way to get the hyphen to `PreviewTextInput`?

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextCompositionManager.AddTextInputHandler(this, new TextCompositionEventHandler(Window_PreviewTextInput));
}

private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I tried using 
this.AddHandler(Window.PreviewTextInputEvent, new TextCompositionEventHandler(Window_PreviewTextInput), true);

to get the handled events. But even this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this but I want to know from experts if there is a problem with my solution or a better way to do this.

In the KeyDown event of the window I am marking the Handled to false. The checkbox sets the Handled to true in the KeyDown and in the Window's KeyDown I am setting it to false and this will call the PreviewTextInput as the event still needs to be handled.

```
public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextCompositionManager.AddPreviewTextInputStartHandler(this, new TextCompositionEventHandler(Window_PreviewTextInput));
            this.AddHandler(Window.KeyDownEvent, new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(Window_KeyDown), true);
        }

private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
        }

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
```

Comment: One obvious thing I would see is a performance issue as the events have to travel more the tree now for some controls.